# I wanted to implement a BST and tried using vector for input

Tags: c++, tree, c++14, binary-tree

I wanted to implement a BST class with a vector and somehow its not working. I just wanted to know the reason why its not working.

The main reason that I can think of that root in the BST always remain **NULL**.

I wanted to experiment ways to use classes in data structures.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* left ;
    Node* right ;

    Node(int val){
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};


class BST{
    public:
    Node* root = NULL;

    void insert(Node* r,int data){
        Node* new_node = new Node(data);
        if(r == NULL){
            r = new_node;
        }

        if(data < r->data){
            if(r->left == NULL){
                r->left = new_node;
            }
            else{
                insert(r->left,data);
            }
        }else if(data > r->data){
            if(r->right == NULL){
                r->right = new_node;
            }
            else{
                insert(r->right,data);
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    BST(vector<int> bst_array){
        for(int i = 0; i<bst_array.size(); i++){
            insert(root,bst_array[i]);
        }
    }

    void print_t(Node* r){
        if(r == NULL){
            cout<<"NULL";
            return;
        }
            
        else{
            print_t(r->left);
            cout<<r->data<<" ";
            print_t(r->right); 
        }
    }
    
};


int main(){

    vector<int> v = {1,3,5,44,23,78,21};

    BST* tr = new BST(v);

    tr->print_t(tr->root);

    return 0;
}
```

There seem to be a logical mistake on my end please help me find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Nothing. It is just going inside the if(r == NULL) [print_t(Node* r) statement everytime.

Comment: Then go one step up to understand *why* `r` is a null pointer when you expect not a null pointer.

Comment: Because `r = new_node` within `insert` ultimately means *nothing* to the caller of the function. `r` is by-value passed to `insert`. Changing it will not affect the caller's copy of that value whence called. `root` remains null after the call, and as a bonus, you leaked memory just to rub salt in the wound.

Comment: *"its not working"* -- this is a useless description of your problem, covering everything from failing to compile to accidentally unleashing [Skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)) on the world. What specifically does not work? What did you observe that led you to believe there is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `root` is never assigned another value after its initialisation to `NULL`. Passing `root` as argument to the `insert` method can never alter `root` itself, as it is not the address of `root` that is passed, but its value.

Some other remarks:

- `insert` always starts by creating a new node, at every step of the recursion. This is a waste of node creation. In the end you just need one new node, so only create it when its position in the tree has been identified.
- The final `else` is not needed, as all it does is execute a `return`, which it would have done anyway without that `else` block
- As `insert` is a method of `BST`, it is a pity that it requires a node as argument. You would really like to just do `insert(data)` and let it take care of it. For that to happen I suggest to move your `insert` method to the `Node` class, where the `this` node takes over the role of the argument. Then the `BST` class could get a wrapping `insert` method that forwards the job to the other `insert` method.
- Instead of `NULL` use `nullptr`.

To solve the main issue, there are many solutions possible. But after making the above changes, it is quite easy to assign to `root` in the simplified `insert` method on the `BST` class.

Here is how it could work:

```
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* left ;
    Node* right ;

    Node(int val){
        data = val;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }

    void insert(int data) {
        if (data < this->data) {
            if (this->left == nullptr) {
                this->left = new Node(data);
            } else {
                this->left->insert(data);
            }
        } else if (data > this->data) {
            if (this->right == nullptr) {
                this->right = new Node(data);
            } else {
                this->right->insert(data);
            }
        }
    }
};

class BST {
    public:
    Node* root = nullptr;

    void insert(int data) {
        if (root == NULL) { // Assign to root
            root = new Node(data);
        } else { // Defer the task to the Node class
            root->insert(data);
        }
    }

    BST(vector<int> bst_array){
        for(int i = 0; i<bst_array.size(); i++){
            insert(bst_array[i]); // No node argument
        }
    }

    /* ...other methods ...*/
}
```